# factorial with for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

```
result = 1
num = 1
while num <= 5: 
    result *= num 
    num = num + 1
print(result) #this gives me 5!
```

however, i would like to do this with for loop. i tried using this

```
result = 1
for num in (1, 6, 1): 
    result *= num 
    print(result) #just to see intermediate calculations
print(result)
```

the result i get = 6 instead of 120.

```
1
6
6
```

was the output i got.

what did i do wrong for the for loop?

Comment: Voting to close as this is a typographical error

Comment: You can use range() or xrange() to loop through 1 to 6 with step size 1.

`for num in xrange(1, 6, 1):`

Comment: missed out on range() in front of the tuple (1, 6).  thanks everyone for their help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you meant to apply that tuple to the range function:

```
for num in range(1, 6, 1):
```

Although `range(1, 6)` will suffice. A step of 1 is the default.

`(1, 6, 1)` is just a tuple of 3 elements, `1`, `6`, and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You just loop in set has three elements 1,6,1. You should replace by `range(1,6)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your for loop:

```
result = 1
for num in range(1, 6): 
    result *= num 
    print(result) 
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        i=i+1
        result=result*i
        
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# The solution which you are looking for, named Factorial
def factorial(n):
    # Initial Number
    result = 1
    # In factorial range must be started by 1
    for num in range(1, n):
        # the main point is that the result should be 
        # multiply a number grater than itself
        result = result * (num + 1)
    return result
print(factorial(5))
```